# Removing some (but not all) occurrences of a type from a pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

`template <typename Pack, typename T, std::size_t... Is> struct remove_some` removes `T` from `Pack` that are the `Is...` T's found.  For example:

```
template <typename...> struct P;   template <typename...> struct Q;

static_assert (std::is_same<
    remove_some<std::tuple<int, char, bool, int, int, double, int>, int, 1,2>,
    std::tuple<int, char, bool, double, int>
>::value, "");

static_assert (std::is_same<
    remove_some<std::tuple<int, char, bool, int, int, double, int>, int, 0,3>,
    std::tuple<char, bool, int, int, double>
>::value, "");

static_assert (std::is_same<
    remove_some<std::tuple<int, char, P<long, int, short>, bool, int, int, double, int>,
        int, 0,1,2,4>,
    std::tuple<char, P<long, short>, bool, int, double>
>::value, "");
```

These assertions have all passed with my current code, but the problem is getting this assertion to pass:

```
static_assert (std::is_same<  // Fails
    remove_some<std::tuple<int, char, P<long, int, Q<int, int, int>, short>, bool, int, int, double, int>, int, 0,1,2>,
    std::tuple<char, P<long, Q<int, int>, short>, bool, int, int, double, int>
>::value, "");
```

i.e. a pack within a pack within a pack, and I cannot seem to pin-point why the failure.  Here is my current code so far, including where I think the mistake is, but a better approach is always welcomed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <typename Pack, typename T, std::size_t Count, typename Output, std::size_t... Is> struct remove_some_h;

template <typename Pack, typename T, std::size_t... Is>
using remove_some = typename remove_some_h<Pack, T, 0, std::tuple<>, Is...>::type;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename T, std::size_t Count, typename... Output, std::size_t I, std::size_t... Is>
struct remove_some_h<P<First, Rest...>, T, Count, std::tuple<Output...>, I, Is...> : remove_some_h<P<Rest...>, T, Count, std::tuple<Output..., First>, I, Is...> {};

// T is found, but it is not the Ith one, so do NOT remove it.  Increase Count by 1 to handle the next T.
template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Rest, typename T, std::size_t Count, typename... Output, std::size_t I, std::size_t... Is>
struct remove_some_h<P<T, Rest...>, T, Count, std::tuple<Output...>, I, Is...> : remove_some_h<P<Rest...>, T, Count + 1, std::tuple<Output..., T>, I, Is...> {};

// T is found, and it is the next one to remove, so remove it and increase Count by 1 to handle the next T.
template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Rest, typename T, std::size_t Count, typename... Output, std::size_t... Is>
struct remove_some_h<P<T, Rest...>, T, Count, std::tuple<Output...>, Count, Is...> : remove_some_h<P<Rest...>, T, Count + 1, std::tuple<Output...>, Is...> {};

// No more indices left, so no more T's to remove and hence just adjoin Rest... to the output.
template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Rest, typename T, std::size_t Count, typename... Output>
struct remove_some_h<P<Rest...>, T, Count, std::tuple<Output...>> {
    using type = P<Output..., Rest...>;
    static constexpr std::size_t new_count = Count;
    using remaining_indices = std::index_sequence<>;
};

// No more types left to check, though there are still some T's left to remove (e.g. from an outerpack that contains this inner pack).
template <template <typename...> class P, typename T, std::size_t Count, typename... Output, std::size_t... Is>
struct remove_some_h<P<>, T, Count, std::tuple<Output...>, Is...> {
    using type = P<Output...>;
    static constexpr std::size_t new_count = Count;
    using remaining_indices = std::index_sequence<Is...>;
};

// No more types left to check, nor any T's left to remove (this is needed to avoid ambiguity).
template <template <typename...> class P, typename T, std::size_t Count, typename... Output>
struct remove_some_h<P<>, T, Count, std::tuple<Output...>> {
    using type = P<Output...>;
    static constexpr std::size_t new_count = Count;
    using remaining_indices = std::index_sequence<>;
};

// The problem case (dealing with inner packs):
template <typename Pack, typename T, std::size_t Count, typename Output, typename IndexSequence> struct remove_some_h_index_sequence;

template <typename Pack, typename T, std::size_t Count, typename Output, std::size_t... Is>
struct remove_some_h_index_sequence<Pack, T, Count, Output, std::index_sequence<Is...>> : remove_some_h<Pack, T, Count, Output, Is...> {};

template <template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class Q, typename... Ts, typename... Rest, typename T, std::size_t Count, typename... Output, std::size_t I, std::size_t... Is>
struct remove_some_h<P<Q<Ts...>, Rest...>, T, Count, std::tuple<Output...>, I, Is...> {  // I is needed to avoid ambiguity.
    static constexpr std::size_t new_count = Count;  // I think this value is wrong?
    using remaining_indices = std::index_sequence<I, Is...>;  // I think this is the wrong sequence?
    using inner = remove_some_h<Q<Ts...>, T, Count, std::tuple<>, I, Is...>;  // Take care of the inner pack first.
    using type = typename remove_some_h_index_sequence<P<Rest...>, T, inner::new_count, std::tuple<Output..., typename inner::type>, typename inner::remaining_indices>::type;
};
```

Comment: First hint: The type actually being generated by the failing case is `std::tuple<char, P<long, Q<int, int>, short>, bool, int, double, int>`.  Missing one `int`.

Comment: "These assertions have all passed with my current code, but problem is getting this assertion to pass" -- requiring that assertion to pass is raw insanity.  `remove_some` doing *that* is far from the principle of least surprise as one can see.  I suspect you need to write different primitives, and compose them to do your task, when you want to do something *that* strange.

Comment: @ Yakk.  I don't think the fix is that drastic.  md51 pointed out a simple fix, but his fix seems to still fail when going one inner pack deeper.  Perhaps the final fix is not too different from his solution.  Also, I don't see how this is insane if we are simply reading the count from left to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching this problem wrong.  Your primitive, which walks a tree of types in a depth-first manner, counting elements of a given type, and removing them at certain indexes, is a ridiculous primitive.  In a sense, it does *too much*, and too specifically.

Instead you should be looking at how existing list-processing functional languages solve problems like this.  They build primitive operations and compose them, instead of hand-writing complex primitives like yours.

The first step is the flat list.  You want to walk a flat list, running a predicate on each element.  If the predicate says so, you want to eliminate the element.  You *also* want to modify the state of the predicate as you go along.

Next, modify the linear-list traverser to be a depth-first traversal of a tree.  This can be done with a predicate mutator (one that takes a predicate, and makes it decend into the contents of arguments after visiting the arguments).

So now you are doing a depth-first traversal of a tree of types, passing through a filter that eliminates types from it.

And **now** we build a predicate that says "remove the nth instances of a type `T`".

--

The point of this is that each of these techniques can be tested indepenently.

Two kinds of approaches that might help is to treat templates as types (a template is a type with a `template<class...Ts> using result=/*...*/;` in it), or to go hana-style and do metaprogramming in constexpr and decltype'd functions with type tags.

```
template<class T>struct tag_type{using type=T;};
template<class T>constexpr tag_type<T> tag{};
```

Tags for hana-style metaprogramming.

Some hana-style type filters:

```
struct filter_never {
  template<class U>
  constexpr std::pair<std::false_type, filter_never>
  operator()(tag_type<U>){ return {}; }
};
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct filter_nth {
  template<class U>
  constexpr std::pair< std::false_type, filter_nth<T, N> >
  operator()(tag_type<U>)const{return {};}
  constexpr std::pair< std::false_type, filter_nth<T, N-1> >
  operator()(tag_type<T>)const{return {};}
};
template<class T>
struct filter_nth<T, 0> {
  template<class U>
  constexpr std::pair< std::false_type, filter_nth<T, 0> >
  operator()(tag_type<U>)const{return {};}
  constexpr std::pair< std::true_type, filter_never >
  operator()(tag_type<T>)const{return {};}
};
```

A filter-merger:

```
template<class...Filters>
struct filter_any:filter_never{};

template<class...>struct types_tag { using type=types_tag; };
template<class...Ts>
constexpr types_tag<Ts...> types{};

template<class...Truth, class...Filters>
constexpr auto merge_filter_results( std::pair<Truth, Filters>... )
-> std::pair<
    std::integral_constant<bool, (Truth{} || ...)>, // C++1z, can write but long in C++11
    filter_any<Filters...>
  >
{ return {}; }

template<class F0, class...Filters>
struct filter_any<F0, Filters...> {
  template<class U>
  constexpr auto operator()(tag_type<U> t)const {
    return merge_filter_results( F0{}(t), Filters{}(t)... );
  }
};
```

`filter_any<Filters...>` merges any number of filters, and applies them to each element.  If any say "discard", the result is discard.

So `,int, 1, 2` becomes `filter_any<filter_nth<int, 1>, filter_nth<int, 2>>`.

This seems complex; but the important part is I just reduced the problem of eliminating multiple elements from the list into testing the ability to eliminate one at a time, and testing the `filter_any`.  Two components, each individually tested.

```
template<class...T0s, class...T1s>
constexpr types_tag<T0s..., T1s...> concat_elements( types_tag<T0s...>, types_tag<T1s...> )
{ return {}; }

template<class Filter>
constexpr types_tag<> filter_elements( Filter, types_tag<> ) { return {}; }

template<class T0, class...Ts, class Filter>
auto filter_elements( Filter, types_tag<T0, Ts...> )
-> decltype(
  concat_elements( std::conditional_t<
      Filter{}(tag<T0>).first,
      types_tag<>,
      types_tag<T0>
    >{},
    filter_elements( Filter{}(tag<T0>).second, types_tag<Ts...> )
  )
)
{ return {}; }
```

and now, barring typos, we can:

```
auto r = filter_elements(
  filter_any<filter_nth<int, 1>, filter_nth<int, 2>>{},
  types_tag<int, char, char, std::string, char, int, char, int, int, char>{}
);
```

and the type of `r` is now

```
types_tag<int, char, char, std::string, char, char, int, char>
```

what is left to do is debugging the crap above, and handling descent.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3f3ebba5acbc10e).

I work on `types_tag`, because taking any template type and transcribing it back and forth to `types_tag` is relatively easy.  The more work we do in lightweight types like `types_tag` the faster we'll work.

All we need is a transcribe:

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class types>
struct transcribe;
template<template<class...>class Z, class types>
using transcribe_t=typename transcribe<Z,types>::type;

template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct transcribe<Z,types_tag<Ts...>>:tag_type<Z<Ts...>> {};
```

and steal:

```
template<class T>
struct as_types;
template<class T>
using as_types_t=typename as_types<T>::type;

template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct as_types<Z<Ts...>>:types_tag<Ts...>{};
```

to move back and forth from an arbitrary package.

```
template<class T, class Filter>
struct filter_elements_out;
template<class T, class Filter>
using filter_elements_out_t=typename filter_elements_out<T,Filter>::type;

template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts, class Filter>
struct filter_elements_out:
  type_tag<
    transcribe_t<Z,
      decltype(filter_elements(Filter{},types<Ts...>{}))
    >
  >
{};
```

which is easy, no?

I did talk about adapting to a depth-first filter.  It takes a bit more effort.

Have the function return `types_tag<...>` instead of true/false and concat back into the original list works better as it turns out.  (Noticed this when I was implementing it).

Here is a filter->polymap (a map that returns a collection), and a depth-first adapter:

```
template<class Filter>
struct filter_to_polymap {
  template<class U>
  constexpr
  std::pair<
    std::conditional_t<
      Filter{}(tag<U>).first,
      types_tag<>,
      types_tag<U>
    >,
    filter_to_polymap<decltype(Filter{}(tag<U>).second)>
  > operator()(tag_type<U>)const {
    static_assert(
      !std::is_same<decltype(Filter{}(tag<U>).second), filter_never>{}
      ,""
    );
    return {};
  }
};

template<class Polymap>
constexpr std::pair<types_tag<>, Polymap> map_elements_ex( Polymap, types_tag<> ) { return {}; }

template<class Polymap, class T0, class...Ts>
constexpr auto map_elements_ex( Polymap p, types_tag<T0, Ts...> )
{
  return std::make_pair(
  concat_elements( 
    p(tag<T0>).first,
    map_elements_ex( p(tag<T0>).second, types<Ts...> ).first
  ),
  map_elements_ex( p(tag<T0>).second, types<Ts...> ).second
  );
}

template<class Polymap, class...Ts>
auto map_elements( Polymap p, types_tag<Ts...> ) {
  return map_elements_ex(p, types<Ts...>).first;
}

template<class Polymap, template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
auto map_elements_tagged( Polymap, tag_type<Z<Ts...>> ) {
  return tag< transcribe_t<Z, decltype(map_elements(Polymap{}, types<Ts...>))> >;
}

template<class Polymap>
struct depth_first_polymap {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  constexpr auto operator()(tag_type<Z<Ts...>>) const {
    auto r = map_elements_ex(*this, types<Ts...>);
    return std::make_pair(
      types<transcribe_t<Z, decltype(r.first)>>,
      r.second
    );
  }
  template<class U>
  constexpr auto operator()(tag_type<U>) const {
    auto r=Polymap{}( tag<U> );
    return std::make_pair(
      r.first,
      depth_first_polymap<decltype(r.second)>{}
    );
  }
};
```

This makes it [easy to solve your problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/914970fa0c34f411).

Comment: @ Yakk   I accept your answer not only because it is an entirely new approach, but because I like it when go harsh on me like this.  But if you look at the other response, his fix to my method (which I tested to work correctly, but never could have thought of) was quite simple, no?

Comment: @prestokeys heh, sure: anyhow, completed the answer now.  It is a first pass -- cleaning it up to be more pure-hana style, or more pure template-style, and removing some redundancy introduced during development should make things happier.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fix for your last `remove_some_h` clause:

```
template <template <typename...> class P, template <typename...> class Q,
          typename... Ts, typename... Rest, typename T, std::size_t Count,
          typename... Output, std::size_t I, std::size_t... Is>
struct remove_some_h<P<Q<Ts...>, Rest...>, T, Count,
                     std::tuple<Output...>, I, Is...> {  // I is needed to avoid ambiguity.
    using inner = remove_some_h<Q<Ts...>, T, Count, std::tuple<>, I, Is...>;  // Take care of the inner pack first.
    using removed = remove_some_h_index_sequence<
        P<Rest...>, T, inner::new_count, std::tuple<Output...,
                                                    typename inner::type>,
        typename inner::remaining_indices>;

    using type = typename removed::type;
    static constexpr auto new_count = removed::new_count;
    using remaining_indices = typename removed::remaining_indices;
};
```

Comment: @ md51   Ok, that fixed the failing static assertion.  But now this assertion fails:  `static_assert (std::is_same<
  remove_some<std::tuple<int, char, P<long, int, Q<int, int, P<int, bool>, int>, short>, bool, int, int, double, int>, int, 0,1,4,5,8>,
  std::tuple<char, P<long, Q<int, int, P<bool>>, short>, bool, int, int, double> >::value, "");`  Failure seems to still creep in when going one nested pack deeper.

Comment: @prestokeys Should be fixed.

Comment: @ md51  Yes it works.  And I tested it with even deeper nesting too.  I would accept your response, except that I trust Yakk that you are fixing a method (my method) that is erroneous to begin with.